# Using laravel blade localization inside react

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, localization

I'm using Laravel localization. - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization
I also use react component in the blade view.
Now i wish to use localization in my react component like this

```
return(
    <button className="btn">
      {{ __('messages.welcome') }}
    </button>
)
```

[image]

How can I make the react component call the translation?

Answer (score 1):

you can use normal js package for that like this package  [laravel-js-localization](https://github.com/andywer/laravel-js-localization)

Answer (score 0):

This sign {{ ]} is just for PHP. "means echo", you can not do that. You'd better use Vue.js to do it.
There's two way to use translation:
first:  put all translation in div attributes
second: use JSON API
Regards